# Does Tornado has other thread to write 'x' and wake up select?

Tags: tornado

We all know that tornado Waker(tornado.platform.posix.Waker) is for waking up the main thread when IOLoop is block in select, so the waker is in other thread?

Comment: Just checked in the debugger - Waker is working in the main thread.

Comment: when the whole thread is block by select, how can the waker working...waker need to write 'x' to the pipe to stop select, but if the main thread is block by select, who can do this thing?

Comment: I got your point. Seems like there was a misunderstanding of the question. As you wrote below, Waker "can wake another thread from select()". Usually some synchronous operations are run in a separate thread, like mongodb's async adapter Motor or run_on_executor functions. While they are running, a Tornado's IOLoop waits in select(). When they finish or get a result, they pass it to the Tornado through add_callback(), which then wakes up the IOLoop from select using wake(). This is how I understand it from reading a source code.

Comment: I think so, thanks...so waker "can wake another thread from select()", because there is indeed another thread like mongo\torMysql\Redis instance...these thread can wake up the select...I get it..